# Flatten vec of vecs of custom structs in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a custom struct and after some processing I have a vector contains vectors of this structs. But I'm stuck in getting flat vector of structs only.

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Hash, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Verse {
    pub book_id: i16,
    pub chapter: i16,
    pub verse: i16,
    pub text: String,
}

fn main() {
    let v1 = Verse {
        book_id: 1,
        chapter: 1,
        verse: 1,
        text: String::from("a"),
    };
    let v2 = Verse {
        book_id: 2,
        chapter: 1,
        verse: 1,
        text: String::from("b"),
    };
    let vv = [[v1], [v2]];
    let flatten = vv.iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<Verse>>();
}
```

And error:

```
error[E0277]: a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<Verse>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&Verse`
  --> src/main.rs:23:39
   |
23 |     let flatten = vv.iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<Verse>>();
   |                                       ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<Verse>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&Verse>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&Verse>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<Verse>``std::vec::Vec<Verse>`
```

But I can't find any examples how to come up with solution.

Comment: `let flatten = vv.iter().flatten().cloned().collect::<Vec<_>>();` or `let flatten = vv.into_iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<_>>();`.

Comment: You're not using vectors but arrays that cannot be consumed by value.

Comment: @Boiethios even is I use `let vv = vec![vec![v1], vec![v2]]` I have the same errors.

Comment: @Stargateur thanks! You solution is works, but it's not clear to my, why for example `let flatten = vv.into_iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<Vesrse>>();` doesn't work, but `Vec<_>` works...

Comment: @avdyushin Yes because you didn't read the answer of the question marked as duplicate

Comment: @avdyushin Rust is complex language, myself I still haven't learn all, you can't expect that I can explain you all in a comment. You can't because compiler will not transform reference `&Verse` to `Verse` for you in this case. So you again need to use `cloned()` like `let flatten = vv.into_iter().flatten().cloned().collect::<Vec<Verse>>();` (that if you **want** `Verse` value and not just reference). But generally avoid copy/clone when it's not necessary. Sorry, my first comment was confusing. The first line produce `Verse` type the second produce `&Verse` type.

Comment: Thanks you guys, I was confused with value/reference types. Now it's clear to me